# PHP update issue and youtube id

Tags: php, youtube

First of all I'm pretty new to PHP.

I've been working on a simple script for my website, but I'm kind of struggling to get it to work.

The plan is when you add a video in another script, the admin has to accept or decline it.
if i choose accept it will update the validation row in table YouTube with accepted and if decline it will update with declined.

Other than that I found this script on another thread, but it won't print out the YouTube id from my link row in MySQL.

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some tips?

```
$url = "$row[link]";

$query_string = array();

parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query_string);

$id = $query_string["v"];
```

My code is given below

```
<?
include("connect.php");

$validation = $_POST["validation"];

if(!empty($validation)){

mysql_query("UPDATE youtube SET validation='$validation' where id ='$id' ");
echo "video has been edited";

} else {

$data = mysql_query("select * from youtube where validation='decline' ");

$url = "$row[link]";

$query_string = array();

parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query_string);

$id = $query_string["v"];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {

echo "<b>$row[name]</b>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<a href='$row[link]' target='_blank'>
<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$id/default.jpg' alt='$row[name]'></a>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<b>$row[title]</b>";
echo "<br>";

echo nl2br($row[description]);
echo "<br>";
?>

<form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST">
<select name="validation">
<option value="declined">Decline</option>
<option value="accepted">Accept</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<?



}


}

?>
```

Comment: Sample you have given is incomplete - you should provide example URL to parse.

Comment: but in my link row its an url, so it should print a url in the $url = "$row[link]"; ?

Comment: Before asking you should try to isolate problem - find minimal self-sufficient code that will reproduce it. Better to put it in 'fiddle'. If you can not do that, and have to post non self-sufficient code which is using some external resource (private database, for example), please, *give us as maximum  information* about missing source data and results you are getting from your code.